Getting the PID from FLAME.call/2
I'm using Mox to mock some modules in my app. Usually, it works fine but I have a function that I'm calling inside FLAME.call/2 and it broke my mock:
** (Mox.UnexpectedCallError) no expectation defined for Zoonk.Storage.StorageAPIMock.optimize!/2 in process #PID<0.5593.0> with args ["16.png", 500]
             (mox 1.1.0) lib/mox.ex:820: Mox.__dispatch__/4
             (zoonk 0.1.0) lib/storage/storage_context.ex:177: Zoonk.Storage.optimize!/2
             (flame 0.2.0) lib/flame/runner.ex:431: anonymous fn/3 in FLAME.Runner.remote_call/4

Apparently, I need to use Mox.allow/3 to allow other processes to share expectations. But I need the PID of that process. How do I find it?
I've tried doing:

GenServer.whereis(Zoonk.FLAME.ImageOptimization)
GenServer.whereis(FLAME.Pool)
GenServer.whereis(FLAME.Runner)
etc.

None of those seem to work.
I know I can :set_mox_global. But, then, I can't run tests asynchronously. So, I'd rather find a way to use Mox.allow/3 instead.
Any ideas?

This was a fancy dive into FLAME internals :)
The issue you have is the actual FLAME.Pool runner is not yet spawned at the moment you call Mox.allow/3. If you’d read the documentation till the end, you’ll see, that mox is ready to handle such cases anyway with a deferred allowance

If the process is not yet started at the moment of allowance definition, it might be allowed as a function, assuming at the moment of invocation it would have been started. If the function cannot be resolved to a pid during invocation, the expectation will not succeed.
allow(MyMock, self(), fn -> GenServer.whereis(Deferred) end)


That said, FLAME.call/2 delegates to FLAME.Pool to start a monitored task. Unfortunately, this task is not named, meaning to get to it’s pid we would need some further investigation. It looks a bit hacky, though, but I frankly doubt it could be done without digging into internals. Probably an issue in FLAME repo to expose task pids would be worth it to create.
Anyway.
Here is the code (with comments) to retrieve the pid of the runner from the pool.
MyApp.MyMod.Mox # the mox to allow expectations
|> allow(self(), fn ->
  :sys.get_state(Zoonk.FLAME.ImageOptimization).callers # callers of Pool
  |> Enum.flat_map(fn {pid, _} -> Process.info(pid)[:links] end) # backlinks
  |> hd() # first one
end)
|> expect(:fun, fn … -> … end)

